# Make an image view every time at launch

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want my splash image to fade after one second after launch.

So on top of the .xib I put an image view with the splash image, (

*first the actual splash screen shows, then when the xib is loaded an image view with the same image is shown, making it look like it's the same splash screen*

)

**I use this code in ViewController.m to fade the image**

```
[UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[ImageLoading setAlpha:0];
[UIImageView commitAnimations];
```

This works, but If the user goes to another xib and later switches back, it shows the 1 second splash screen again.

**I tried this in Viewcontroller.m**

```
-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

[UIImageView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIImageView setAnimationDuration:1.0];
[ImageLoading setAlpha:0];
[UIImageView commitAnimations];

return YES;

}
```

But apparently it's not getting called.

**Is there any other way, to make this image view fade at launch?**

Thanks a lot,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

set a property in your app delegate .
eg `@property(nonatomic,assign) BOOL isFirstTime;`

in appdelegate's  `-(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOption`s method, set it to `NO`.

Then in the viewController, check this value.
If it is YES, show the animation and set it to NO.
If it is NO, do nothing.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to do this is to have a flag a bool value and pass it to the view controller then and check it if it is launched. and only show the splash screen if the value is false. something like

```
     if (!notShowSplashScreen) { 
...Your code ...
 notShowSplashScreen = TRUE
}
```

(default bool value is set to true so you don't have to pass it every time you show the screen)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in `viewDidLoad` method in your `rootViewController`

Answer (score 0):

You can add a sleep in the appDelegate like this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 
    [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:1];
}
```

Comment: This will just show the default.png a second longer, not the dissolve animation I was going for :)